# how to manually set Request.IsAuthenticated = true in Asp.Net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 MVC application - one application works as single sign on and I login from this application and create cookie to pass user's credentials into second application - and in second application I get user name from that cookie and setting authentication of that user name  from following code

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Session["User"].ToString(), true /* createPersistentCookie */);

but I still get Request.IsAuthenticated as False

can any one please help how do I Authenticate my request ?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look at shared authentication, here is an answered question about it

[How can I share .net (C#) based authenticated session between web forms and MVC2 applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161562/how-can-i-share-net-c-based-authenticated-session-between-web-forms-and-mvc2)

Answer (score 0):

guys are discussing similar case if following link

[Clickie here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread2271-how-to-pass-session-values-between-two-applications.aspx)

check if this is any good to you:)